# Apple push notifications and Emoji characters

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I recently found this very interesting article on APNS and Emoji characters:  [EASY APNS - Just for fun](http://www.easyapns.com/category/just-for-fun)

It contains a list with all supported Emojis. However, I couldn't get them to display in my push notifications. All I get is the code, not the image. For example, if I add \ue415 (a smiley) to my message, I never see the image, just the code.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *emoji = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0xe415];
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea, how I'd achieve the same within php?

Answer (score 3):

check out this site http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/

he does the emoji in php.

i use this command to achieve a emoji on the iphone.

emoji_unified_to_softbank("\xee\x80\xac");

Q

Comment: @Quintin I have the same issue so I have tried the script that you have mentioned above in that script when i am trying to pass data of emojis, it returns as it is code not symbol.Do you have any suggestion regarding solution to this issue? its working on web page but not in apple push message.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649050/emojis-support-in-apple-push-notification?noredirect=1#comment23947351_16649050

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Rubymotion for iOS dev the you can use the softbank code converted like this:
softbank code:  U+E04A
Rubymotion string sent as push: "This is a sun with rays emoji \ue04a"