# How can I add color pictures to push-notification?

Tags: iphone, ipad, push-notification

I'm programming for iPhone. How can I add color pictures to push-notification?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not really colored pictures. That images are part of a font called emoij. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441027/apple-push-notifications-and-emoji-characters) post explaines everything you want i think. It shows how to implement Emoij characters in a Push Notification. ;-)

Sandro Meier